# How can merge two beam elements without section lossing in abaqus?

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to merge two parts in abaqus but I have got a problem. I have two parts with different sections and materials. First I mesh them then I make orphan mesh of each of them . then I assemble the orphan meshes and merge  them . after this I face three different situations . 
First: the new part ( which is made of merging two parts) contains two parts but both them have the same section and material.
Second: the new part contains two part but in property module it gets yellow and it means it has assigned section tow times.
Third: the new part contains two parts and each of them has their own section and material  and this is what I need to happen.
Everytime I do the same procedure but each time one different situation happens . I am really getting confused . I whoud be so glad for any help.

Comment: why are you working with orphan meshes in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a set on each initial part (e.g. set ALL1 and ALL2) and these sets will be transferred to the resulting merged part (PART1-ALL1...) so you can fix the section/property assignment easily after merge.

Comment: i did it but both of the sets refer to the same thing . in fact i can t choose them seprately

Comment: They should be separate sets. Make sure you have different names for these sets in each initial part (I would also try disable "Merge Nodes" as a last option). I just tried this and it works for Abaqus 2017 at least.